# Sequence of actions after pressing a submit button

Tags: react-native, activity-indicator

I have a button linked to resetPasswordHandler - whereby after I have input the users email, and the request is a success, a pop-up alert will appear asking to check the user's email, followed by the modal closing, and the state of the modal reset.

I thought this (see code below) would work. But when I press the submit button, the modal resets and closes before the pop-up appears.

I can't quite tell where I've gone wrong.

```
    resetPasswordHandler = () => {
    console.log("Resetting Password")
    firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(this.state.controls.email.value).then(
        alert("Please Check Your Email")
    ).then(
        this.reset()
    ).then(
        this.refs.resetPasswordModal.close()
    ).catch(function(e){
        alert(e);
    })
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `.then(...)` on a `Promise`, you should pass a function (similar to passing a function to a button press handler, for example).

```
myPromise
  .then(() => this.props.dispatch(someAction()))
```

Right now, you are calling the function instead of passing it.

Your code should look as follows, keeping this in mind:

```
firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(this.state.controls.email.value)
  .then(
    () => alert("Please Check Your Email")
  )
  .then(
    () => this.reset()
  )
  .then(
    () => this.refs.resetPasswordModal.close()
  )
  .catch(function(e){
    alert(e);
  })
```

(I used arrow functions in my example, you can also use `function`-syntax, of course)

You did this correctly in your `.catch`, but seemed to have missed it in the other calls!

You can also use the `async` `await` syntax, which gives your code a more synchronous feel:

```
resetPasswordHandler = async () => {
  try {
    // Notice the "await" before calling the reset function, which returns a promise.
    await firebase
      .auth()
      .sendPasswordResetEmail(this.state.controls.email.value)

    alert("Please Check Your Email")

    this.reset()

    this.refs.resetPasswordModal.close()
  }
  catch(e) {
    alert(e);
  }
};
```

If your wrapping function has the `async` keyword, you can resolve promises in a more synchronous manner by calling them with `await`. The wrapping function then returns a promise itself that resolves when its body has completed.

Comment: Haha silly me. Thanks @stinodes for the detailed explanation :D

Comment: No problem, happens to the best. Good luck!